# Display only nodes matched by variable length relationship query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query with a variable length relationship:

```
MATCH p = (a1:Article)-[:REFERENCES*3..]->(a2:Article) RETURN p;
```

This gets me the desired results in table and text view. However, in graph view it also displays nodes with fewer relationships. How can I filter those out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what your desired results are? Using a variable length means you get all nodes in the range.

RETURN p will return entire path, including all nodes in path.

```
MATCH p = (a1:Article)-[:REFERENCES*3]->(a2:Article) RETURN a2
```

should return the nodes 3 hops away from a1.

Comment: I want graph view to show only the nodes involved in those chains of three or more hops, but it's also showing me isolated nodes or nodes connected by only 1 or 2 hops.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with your Neo4j Browser settings.
The 'Connect result nodes' option is enabled by default. All relationships between the nodes matched in your query will be displayed with this enabled.
This happens even if you haven't explicitly mentioned that path/pattern/realtionship in your query.

You can find this option in the Browser Settings, available in the bottom left corner of your Neo4j Browser.

[Adjust the Graph Vizualization settings in the Browser Settings drawer](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/browser-settings/#adjust-in-browser)

[image: Connect Result Nodes]